# <httpErrors> tag - respect tilde (~) or similar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

Using the old `<customErrors>` tag in web.config files, it was possible to write;

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPage/E500" />
</customErrors>
```

And the `~` in `redirect="~/ErrorPage/E500"` is replaced by the root of the site.

However, in using `<httpErrors>` instead, I found the tilde isn't respected;

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="~/ErrorPage/E500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
</httpErrors>
```

The only way to 'fix' it is for me to put an absolute path from the root of my site;

```
  <error statusCode="500" path="/MySites/SiteRoot/ErrorPage/E500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
```

which feels really wrong. Is there any way to fix this or quote it in such a way that the URLs are relative to the site root?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find a better solution? Facing same problem.